# Trying to get property of non-object php variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and I have made a function to return name of  the user. Here is the code:

```
$this->db->where('u_id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get('users');
$data = $query->result_array();

$string = $data->u_name.' '.$data->u_surname;

return $string;
```

When I am using this function i get this error:

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object and recall the line with
>   $string = [...]

Comment: You requested an array (`[]`) but you're trying to access it as an object (`->`)

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loop:

```
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    echo $string = $data['u_name'].' '.$data['u_surname'];
}
```

Comment: result_array() method returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced. Typically you’ll use this in a foreach loop. @TomaszChwicewski

Comment: refer : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html @TomaszChwicewski

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.In codeigniter,The `row()` returns the matched first row according to your condition in object form.

```
$this->db->where('u_id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get('users');
$data = $query->row();//change here

$string = $data->u_name.' '.$data->u_surname;

//echo $string;
return $string;
```

for more see [Codeigniter Result Sets](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try  this code to return

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where(array('u_id'=>$id));
$query=$this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows()()>0)
{
$data = $query->result();
return $data->u_name.' '.$data->u_surname;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the function you chose to generate results for you query.

```
$data = $query->result_array();
```

result_array() returns the results in an array even if you only had one result, so when you try to $data->u_name for instance, you have this error because the array does not have that property.

You can do a foreach on $data and perform your logic or use other methods to get the result from the query like $query->row_array();

Take a look on the codeigniter documentation: [Generating Query Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)